# QGIS - Vector to Raster

Tags: qgis-3

I manage to use the expression to create a basic footprint of some buildings and then use geometry by expression. But I having problem to get the sizing of the footprint to be exactly the size that was in it attribute. Length 500m by  width 120m.

I had projected my points to us something like EPSG:3857 or IGNF:WGS84WMSV with meters as unit. But I could never get the size of the footprint to be that exact sizing. (492 x 118 something like this.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As the Bot says additional details are needed.  But your choice of symbology will not be reflected in converting any point dataset to a raster.  You could make a map with your points symbolized and sized for your desired scale, then export it to a raster at the desired scale and use that but whether that might work and at what scales and symbol sizes hinges on what you ultimately want to do.